# how to install pecl on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: php, ubuntu, pecl

I am using ubuntu 18.04 docker image.
and install

```
apt install php
```

and i want to install xdebug but there is no pecl.
how to install pecl?

Answer (score 7):

I installed pecl on ubuntu 20.04 using `apt install php-dev` (php7.4). this may be useful.

Comment: That's the answer I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about docker. Here are my notes for installing XDebug on Ubuntu 18.04 (in HyperV VM) for PhpStorm. There may be some mistakes but this worked for me.

```
apt install php-xdebug

##### Ubuntu Server #####
mkdir -p /var/log/xdebug
touch /var/log/xdebug/xdebug.log
chown -R www-data:www-data /var/log/xdebug

nano /etc/php/7.2/mods-available/xdebug.ini
################################################################################################################################################################################################################
# The default value for zend_extension is enough. But if you want to change, go to /usr/lib/php/ and find latest folder with xdebug.so (in my case '20180731') and make full path to provide in zend_extension #
################################################################################################################################################################################################################
xdebug.default_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1
xdebug.idekey = PHPSTORM
xdebug.remote_log = /var/log/xdebug/xdebug.log
;zend_extension=/usr/lib/php/20180731/xdebug.so
;xdebug.remote_host = 127.0.0.1
;xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
;xdebug.remote_handler = dbgp
;xdebug.remote_mode = req

systemctl restart apache2
```

Answer (score 1):

Run the command below to install php-pear, then you can use "pecl".

> sudo apt install php-pear